# I have to click twice for jQuery function to run

Tags: jquery, html, css

when the screen resolution on my website gets to the width of that of a phone or an iPad then i made it turn into a bar with a image when that is clicked i want a bar to drop down with the navbar but easier to use however it must be clicked twice for the function to be ran. If anyone could help it would be great!! :)

```js
function onTogglePan() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
    $("#navhide").css("display", "block");
    $("#navhide").css("visibility", "visible");
  } else {
    $("#navhide").css("display", "none");
    $("#navhide").css("visibility", "hidden");
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navshowmenu">
  <a id="showmenu" onclick="onTogglePan()">
    <img src="ico/ham.png" style="height: 52px; width: 52px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px; display: inline-block;">
  </a>
  <button onclick="onTogglePan()">Drop</button>
</div>
<div id="navhide">I am #navhide</div>
```

Comment: Per default clicks is false, that means first click - hide, second click show, what do you want to receive? And why do you change display an visibility? If display is none, visibility has no more effect.

Comment: @axel.michel By default the mobile navbar is invisible when the button is clicked i want it to become visible by users. Do you mind showing me what you mean? thanks for the reply man! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure what you are looking for, but I try to explain

*This is what you do:*

```
function onTogglePan() {
    // since you don't set data-clicks per default the 
    // first value of clicks is false
    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
    if (clicks) {
        // clicks is true - show the bar
        // this happens on second click
        $("#navhide").css("display", "block");
    } else {
        // clicks is false (hide the bar)
        // this happens on first click
        $("#navhide").css("display", "none");
    }
    $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
};
```

I guess you want it the other way round. so if you simply switch the conditions using `if (!clicks)` instead `if (clicks)` it should work. Anyway, you might not need such an attribute. You also could check the visibility:

```
function onTogglePan() {
    var nav = $('#navhide');
    // if is visible hide, otherwise show
    var vis = (nav.is(':visible')) ? 'none' : 'block';
    nav.css("display", vis);        
};
```

See your [updated example here](https://jsfiddle.net/j4xkyas1/7/).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this ?(Just a css solution)

```js
function onTogglePan() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
    $("#navhide").css("display", "block");
    $("#navhide").css("visibility", "visible");
  } else {
    $("#navhide").css("display", "none");
    $("#navhide").css("visibility", "hidden");
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navshowmenu">
  <a id="showmenu" onclick="onTogglePan()">
    <img src="ico/ham.png" style="height: 52px; width: 52px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px; display: inline-block;">
  </a>
  <button onclick="onTogglePan()">Drop</button>
</div>
<div id="navhide" style="  visibility: hidden;">I am #navhide</div>
```

Please tall me if is this, I don't understand if the problem is about the doubleclick or about the nav menu

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your [a] tag and put the id="showmenu" on your [button] tag